# Oracle SQL - WHERE clause behavior

Tags: sql, oracle

I seem to be causing all types of shenanigans

simple query with varchar2 column, nothing complicated

1)

```
select distinct 
name AS CLUSTER_NAME
FROM xtern_app_info a RIGHT JOIN cluster_farm b
ON a.app_cluster = b.name
where a.app_cluster = 'ASLDKJASKDJFASKDJF'
ORDER BY cluster_name desc;
```

zero rows, expected

2)

```
select distinct 
name AS CLUSTER_NAME
FROM xtern_app_info a RIGHT JOIN cluster_farm b
ON a.app_cluster = b.name
where a.app_cluster <> 'ASLDKJASKDJFASKDJF'
ORDER BY cluster_name desc;
```

returns 224 rows, note "=" in WHERE

3)

If I remove where I get 226 rows, why???

```
select distinct 
name AS CLUSTER_NAME
FROM xtern_app_info a RIGHT JOIN cluster_farm b
ON a.app_cluster = b.name
--where a.app_cluster = 'ASLDKJASKDJFASKDJF'
ORDER BY cluster_name desc;
```

4) 
you can replace 'ASLDK...' with any text and you get same result, this is crazy

Comment: The issue is `NULL` values.  Almost any comparison to `NULL` (including `<>`) returns a `NULL` value -- and `NULL` is treated as false.

Comment: @Gordon, I tried nvl() in where clause but same result, the null values are caused by the outer joins, so I still can't use them? thank you though

Comment: @aymanzone you probably want to move that clause from the where clause into the join condition.

Comment: If you rewrite the query as a normal `left join` I think it becomes a lot clearer what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by Gordon, add an `OR` condition in `WHERE` clause of your 2nd query.

2)

```
select distinct 
name AS CLUSTER_NAME
FROM xtern_app_info a RIGHT JOIN cluster_farm b
ON a.app_cluster = b.name
where a.app_cluster <> 'ASLDKJASKDJFASKDJF' OR a.app_cluster IS NULL
ORDER BY cluster_name desc;
```

Those two mysterious entries should be NULL if I am not wrong.

Comment: Gordon was right, the null is caused by the outter join. But when I used nvl() in where clause why do I still get same result? oO

Comment: What are you replacing NULLs with in nvl()?